# select all rows with distinct and condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, row, distinct

Hi guys I new in mySQL and I have problem with query. I was trying to write some Query which get me all records from table and if I have two records with the same date i need get only record between this two which have manual_selection = 1.

So result should be all records from my table except id = 1401 and id = 1549

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQuTO.png)

I tried to combine how can I get this records like this:

```
SELECT * FROM project.score WHERE project_id = 358 
AND crawled_at IN(SELECT crawled_at FROM project.score WHERE project_id = 358 
AND manual_selection = 1 GROUP BY crawled_at)
ORDER BY crawled_at;      

SELECT * FROM project.score WHERE project_id = 358 
GROUP BY crawled_at HAVING manual_selection = 1;
```

but all my way always get only rows with manual_selection = 1. I havent idea how can I distinct rows with duplicate "crawled_at" on case where manual_selection = 1. Can someone help me?

Comment: You could use a combination of `SELECT DISTINCT(field)` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: but I need condition if I have two rows with the same date i get only one with manual_selection = 1, I havent idea how can I do this

Comment: it'll be waayy easier to do this using a script like `php` rather than trying to make a mysql query

Comment: i think about it. Just got all records and choose the specific in loop but I think it is probably with query too, if someone can show example i will be gratefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select main.id, main.project_id, main.crawled_at, main.score, main.manual_selection
from dcdashboard.moz_optimization_keywords as main
left join dcdashboard.moz_optimization_keywords as non_manual_selection on non_manual_selection.crawled_at = main.crawled_at and non_manual_selection.manual_selection != 1
group by main.crawled_at;
```

Result with data set from question:

```
+------+------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+
| id   | project_id | crawled_at          | score | manual_selection |
+------+------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+
|  807 |        360 | 2016-02-06 00:00:00 |    76 |                0 |
| 1001 |        360 | 2016-02-20 00:00:00 |    76 |                0 |
|  223 |        360 | 2016-11-28 00:00:00 |    76 |                0 |
|  224 |        360 | 2016-12-05 00:00:00 |    76 |                0 |
|  670 |        360 | 2016-12-19 00:00:00 |    76 |                0 |
| 1164 |        360 | 2017-04-19 00:00:00 |    78 |                1 |
| 1400 |        360 | 2017-09-13 00:00:00 |    96 |                1 |
| 1548 |        360 | 2017-09-15 00:00:00 |    96 |                1 |
+------+------------+---------------------+-------+------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: this work nice. When I have two records with the same date this query return me one of both but with manual_selection = 0

Comment: For me it returns a record with manual_selection = 1 (in case there are 2 records with the same date). At least, with your data set it is like this. Check again, please.

Comment: sorry but when I was testing it my result is't the same as Your

Comment: We have the same results, that's great! Next question: is this result what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, I have different result You did not include project_id and it take manual_selection with 0

Comment: Well, you have added sample table with 10 rows, and you need a SQL that returns all records except id = 1401 and id = 1549. My SQL does exactly this.
If you need another result - please update your question with sample date (as a code, not as image) and expected result, and we could look again.